# Django Master/Detail Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a two classes that define two models

```
class Master(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.CharField(default = 'R')

class Detail(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    from = models.ForeignKey(Master)
```

The view:

```
def list_view(request):
    masters = master.objects.filter()
    context = {'masters': masters}
    return render_to_response('list.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

The template:

```
{% for master in masters %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ master.date }}</td>
        <td>{{ master.status }}</td>
        <td>{# THIS #}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to show detail names in {# THIS #} section, but I don't know how to modify the View for that. How can I access to details for the master in template?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? There is no additional info in the detail model, what do you want to display ?

Comment: Detail belongs to Master by the "from" field, this is only a example for my real model.

Comment: I forgot to add "name" field in the Detail model.

Comment: you might want to modify the question to show what details you would want to show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this to get the `names`

```
{% for master in masters %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ master.date }}</td>
        <td>{{ master.status }}</td>
        <td>
           {% for detail in master.detail_set.all %}
               {{detail.name}}<br/>
           {% endfor %}        
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```